# How can I open Android alert dialog after some time of loading my app?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I want to show my android alert dialog after 20 seconds of opening the app. What are the changes I should make in my MainActivity.java file?

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    //Do something after 20s
  // Write your code to display AlertDialog here
  }
}, 20000);
```

Comment: As soon as context would changed (e.g. rotate screen) this would not work. Make the handler static to not leak the activity.

Comment: @ViktorYakunin IMHO it's not handler leaks the Activity but anonymous Runnable implementation (almost every answer for this question has the same issue)

Comment: @Selvin You're right. Static handler should solve the problem. handler.postDelayed should be in onCreate checking that instanceState is null :)

Answer (score 1):

Do like that, First create Handler to open alert dialog after 20 seconds

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            openAlert();
        }
    }, 20000);
```

Here is Alert Dialog code

```
private void openAlert() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            .setTitle("SignOut")
            .setMessage("TYPE YOUR MESSAGE HERE")
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            // do want you want to do here
                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                        }
                    }).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert).show();

}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score -1):

Create Handle to open Alert after 20 second

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        alertDialog();
    }
}, 20000);
```

Create Method name alertDialog.

```
private void alertDialog() {
new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        .setTitle("SignOut")
        .setMessage("MESSAGE")
        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            int which) {
                        // code here
                    }
                })
        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            int which) {
          // nothing to do
                    }
                }).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert).show();}
```

Happy to Help and Happy Coding...

Answer (score -2):

In onCreate use Handler method.

```
final ProgressDialog dialog=new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

dialog.setTitle("Loading...");
dialog.setMessage("Please wait.");
dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
dialog.setCancelable(false);
dialog.show();

Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}, 5000);
```